# Windows 8 Evaluation Edition, No iso seems to have been downloaded?

Tags: windows-8-preview, iso-image

I've downloaded the Windows 8 Evaluation Edition and got a zip. In this zip, I don't appear to have an ISO image? Have Microsoft stopped supplying it? I wanted to copy the ISO to a memory stick to install from.

Cheers,

Comment: So what *was* in the ZIP? Are you sure the process completed properly?

Comment: @Karan It looks like everyhting I need, there's a 3 or for 4 folders, "boot", "efi", "sources" and "support" and a few files including a setup.exe. I can't run the exe without getting an error and I presume I shouldn't be trying to anyway. It looks like I just need an ISO.

Answer (score -1):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-download

Make sure you double check the hash to make sure it is the right file, I've seen in some cases mind you a computer viewing ISO's as zip or rar archives, as to why this is, it's usually a setting in whatever zip/rar program you use.